# Few people who are worth listening

Tags: meaning-in-context

*Convey the message as you would speak it. **Few people who are worth listening to speak in sentences of more than 30 words**.*

Could you please help me with understanding the bold sentence. I roughly understand the meaning: most of people are not used to listening to sentences containing more than 30 words. But the way the sentence is constructed is for me confusing. I suppose that the subject is "people" but where is the predicate?

Comment: The headline should be "Few people who are worth listening to".

Comment: That would render the question nonsensical @Gnasher. The preposition *to* is the reason for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Few people *[who are worth listening to]* speak in sentences of more than 30 words.

It seems what confuses you is the preposition *to* after *listening*. It belongs to the clause, and it's not an [infinitive marker](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/infinitive-marker).

The sentence thus means that "few good speakers use sentences with more than 30 words", *good speakers* being the people **worth listening to**.

> It's worth **listening to** them.
>   They're worth **listening to**.